# UI for a java lib

Tags: java, web-services, user-interface

I have a java library that generates a report given some simple input parameters. Currently its a console app. I wanted to create an extremely simple UI for this. What is the quickest way to achieve this ? Are there alternatives other than embedding this library in an application server and then creating a web server that will call it to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Why a web server? Creating simple GUI with Java's swing is simple enough, and it'll allow you to use the library directly.

Another option is to write a simple GUI application that'll run the console application you already have. If you are using Windows I recommend using [HTA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) for the GUI, and [WScript.Shell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for running the console application. If you are using Linux, you might want to check out [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) and use the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module for running the console application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, you can use SWT, WindowBuilder plugins.
http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/
http://www.eclipse.org/swt/